# Array as argument and using the array in the new function in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var filterKeys = ["hello this is javascript", "Movies"];
var title= "Hello"
searchKeyInNo = keySearch(filterKeys, title)

function KeySearch(filteredArray, searchKey) {
    var flag=0
    for (var i = 0; i<filteredArray.count; i++) {
        //array operations
        flag=1
    }
    return flag
}
```

```
var filterKeys = ["hello this is javascript", "Movies"];
var title= "Hello"
searchKeyInNo = keySearch(filterKeys, title)

function KeySearch(filteredArray, searchKey) {
    var tempArray = filteredArray
    var flag=0
    for (var i = 0; i<tempArray.count; i++) {
        //array operations
        flag=1
    }
    return flag
}
```

Can we use passed array as paramneter as a function array?
Can we pass and use the entire array as argument?
I even tried the second piece of code that I added a new array to copy the argument array to process the function scoped array.

UPDATE: VS Code never showed up suggestion for argumentarray.length. Thanks. WORKS NOW!

Comment: You can absolutely pass an array (or even larger structures) to functions and reference them inside, yes. Why wouldn't you? No copy is created at any point in your code. It's just a memory address pointing to the single array you declared in the first line. Also, typos. And please don't add unrelated tags to your questions.

Comment: `var tempArray = filteredArray` does not copy the array.

Comment: Did you try using `.length` to get the length of the array?  Instead of .count which doesn't exist?  https://jsfiddle.net/y9fwa4bn/

Comment: *Very* simple test: `function KeySearch(filteredArray, searchKey) { console.log(filteredArray); }` or debug using browser tools.  Learning basic debugging will help you more than you can realise in the long run.

Comment: @herbertclark are you sure? array.count is not a standard method. Are you using a library?

Comment: @herbertclark `.count` does not work. It will return undefined

Comment: @herbertclark I have updated my answer with a use case, you can check that out

Comment: Thanks everyone. I had found out array.length worked. VS Code never showed suggestions when I type on argument name array.length, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You were using `.count` instead of `.length` on the filtered array to get the count of elements.

```js
function KeySearch(filteredArray, searchKey) 
{

    var flag=0
    for (var i = 0; i<filteredArray.length; i++)
    {
       if(filteredArray[i].toLowerCase()
           .includes(searchKey.toLowerCase()))
       {
          flag++
       }
    }
   return flag
};

console.log(KeySearch(["hello this is javascript", "Movies"], "Hello"))
```